# How to build a wooden ladder for a loft bed?

Tags: wood, screws, furniture, bedroom

I want to build a five foot ladder for my 6 ft loft bed that's being cut down to 4ft tall because it's too close to my ceiling. My bed is going to be in front of my window which is on my shortest wall.

How do I build a ladder to meet these requirements?

Comment: Is the ladder going to be part of the bed or detachable?

Answer (score 4):

A nice ladder can be built similar to the following. Use 1x4 sized material and bore holes through it to accept closet pole for rungs. Select the angle of the vertical rails to suit your space and desired usage preferences. Rung spacing should be even - but not too close together.

Ladder can be simply screwed through the side rail of the bed into the edge of the vertical ladder rail.

[image]